# How can I turn off generation of Dynamic elements by Histogram?

Tags: visualization, histograms, output

By default `Histogram` generates `Graphics` expression with embedded `Dynamic` constructs as can be seen by looking on its `InputForm`. Is it possible to switch off generation of any `Dynamic` constructs and get non-interactive `Graphics` from `Histogram`?

P.S. There are two reasons to turn off interactivity:

1) Interactivity is not needed when preparing graphics for `Export`.

2) Unnecessary `Dynamic` elements complicate generated `Graphics` expression and make difficult to modify it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `$PerformanceGoal` set to `"Quality"` by default, `Histogram` will generate tooltips for all the bars, which are dynamic objects. You can disable this with the option `PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"`.

```
With[{data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 1000]},
    FreeQ[InputForm@Histogram[data, PerformanceGoal -> #], Tooltip | DynamicBox]
]& /@ {"Speed", "Quality"}

(* {True, False} *)
```